# Print transaction status on TextArea

Tags: java, swing, design-patterns

I am developing a project which does the following :

1.truncate a temporary table T1.

2.insert some thousand rows into temporary table T1.

3.Execute a procedure which has some commit statements in it.

4.insert rows from table T1 to other identical table(with respect to structure) T2

5.Execute 2 more procedures.

Now i have made a swing UI which contains TextArea on which i want to print transaction status. Something like this

Reading Excel File..
Validating Excel File..
inserting entries into table T1.. and so on

I have made the following method to update status at each step.

```
public void updateStatus(String message){
        String temp = this.statusText.getText();
        this.statusText.setText(temp  + message +  "\n");
}
```

Calling this method along with statements where i do

`log.debug(message)` does the job for me ! However this complicates my code design. Every DAO Component now depends on this method. Can anyone suggest me a better design option.

Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> log.debug(message) does the job for me ! However this complicates my
>   code design. Every DAO Component now depends on this method. Can
>   anyone suggest me a better design option.

- you have an issue with [Concurency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html), wrap statusText.append(message +  "\n"); to `invokeLater`,
- Swing is single threaded, and all updates to the already visible Swing GUi must be done on [Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)
- maybe you can look at [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html), nothing clear from posted description, only that could be hard and long running, talking about EDT issue
- reduce procesors consuption and to use proper methods for appending a new `String` to already visible `JTextArea`, use `statusText.append(message +  "\n");` instead of quite hard

.

```
String temp = this.statusText.getText(); // take all string from JTextArea
this.statusText.setText(temp  + message +  "\n"); // append() a new line to
```

Comment: Swing worker seems to be a nice option. However in my case only a single instance of Program will run at a time . In that case should i go for Swing Worker ??

Comment: yes SwingWorker is by default not reusable, shareable, a new run equals a new instance