# Object Oriented Program Design Questions

Tags: java, oop

I am relatively new to Java and am having trouble coming up with a truly object oriented design for a program I am working on. Here is a background to the program. The program is a gui based computer telephony application that monitors a phone and acts as a callerID (among other things). My current design is as follows. I have created the following classes.

MainWindow-this is the main window of the gui

Phone-this models the actual device

PopUpWindow-this models the pop up window that pops up on an event in the Phone class

PhoneMessenger-this sends a message to another device when an event happens in the phone class

The part I am having trouble with is that when an event happens in the Phone class I want it to update a value in the MainWindow class. I have the program working by constructing a static class variable MainWindow window in the MainWindow class and using static methods to change the values of the MainWindow class upon events in the Phone class. It works fine but I don't think this follows object oriented design principles as the Phone class now has access to all of the internal values of the MainWindow class. If someone could help me out with the design that would be amazing.

Comment: Are you using Swing ? IF yes i have answer

Comment: Model view controller, my friend.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to use a custom `EventListener` object.

From the `Phone` class, let's say you want there to be a ringing event that displays in the main window. Create an interface like this:

```
public interface RingListener {    
    public void ringing();
}
```

In the Phone class, create a method call `addRingListener(RingListener listener)` and store listeners added in a `List`, such as an `ArrayList`.

In the `MainWindow` class, store an instance of your `Phone` object and add a `RingListener` to it, implementing the abstract ringing method. Then type in your code for what happens.

```
phone.addRingListener(new RingListener() {

    @Override
    public void ringing() {
        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

In the `Phone` class, whenever the event happens, iterate through all of the `RingListeners` in your List and call the ringing method.

```
//Ringing happens!
for (RingListener listener : ringListeners) {
    listener.ringing();
}
```

This is just a quick overview of how the `EventListener` ideology works. I'd suggest taking a look at `ActionListener` and see how it works, as well as searching for some tutorials on how to create your own custom listeners.

Comment: I think `RingListener` should be an interface instead.

Answer (score 1):

1. That's probably because you have all the classes in a single package and you are using no access modifiers and thus making all members `package-protected` (perhaps `package-public` is a better name).  Use access modifier `private` for member variables and/or separate classes in different packages more logically.
2. If I understand your design correctly, shouldn't you be using `class PhoneMessenger` to deliver events?  In this case, don't think in terms of "update a value in the MainWindow".  Think in terms "an event X happened in the phone and I'm going to notify interested parties (`MainWindow`)".  When `MainWindow` receives this event, it is its responsibility to decide what to do (change the value of the variable in this case), not `class Phone`.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to aware about **OPEN CLOSE PRINCIPLE**. This is for oo design approach. and try to use interface which limits the scope of any class with defined methods. To access any object's value, always go for a [POJO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object) class. Here are the links which you needed how to design efficiently.
[1.Open Close Principle](http://www.oodesign.com/open-close-principle.html)
[2. Interface Segregation Principle](http://www.oodesign.com/interface-segregation-principle.html)
[3.other design principles](http://www.oodesign.com/design-principles.html)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my question. I was facing a **similiar** problem. However the users of SO are very smart. Have a look at this --> [Print transaction status on TextArea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18442483/print-transaction-status-on-textarea)